# Issue using replace function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to encrypt a word and than replace it in the given text for that i am using **replace()** in **python**. This method is able to replace the word but keeps the original one in the text also. Below is my code

```
import subprocess
import bz2
import base64
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cat = subprocess.Popen(["hadoop", "fs", "-cat", "/user/cloudera/xxx.dat"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cat.stdout:
    code = line.split('|')[0]
    if (code == "ID"):
        name = line.split('|')[5]
        address = line.split('|')[11]
        ciphername = base64.b64encode(bz2.compress(name))
        cipheraddr = base64.b64encode(bz2.compress(address))
        line.replace(name,ciphername).replace(address,cipheraddr)
        print line
```

**Sample:**

```
ID|1|ZXD0629|ZXD0629||HODJON||11383129|M|||221 B POLLARD RD��KAsODK�TBN�37764|||||||629Z800060|480837
```

**Output:**

```
'ID|1|ZXD0629|ZXD0629||QlpoOTFBWSZTWbk9uLgAAAIGCAbRiAACACAAMQZMQQaMItAUVNzxdyRThQkLk9uLgA==||11383129|M|||QlpoOTFBWSZTWT0tjHQAAAQeCEAALeAkDdQAAgAgADFNMjExMQpo0ZqBmowcuKOA3JhB1VMGcoxTGvi7kinChIHpbGOg|||||||QlpoOTFBWSZTWc5EbhIAAAQKAFNgABAgACEpppkIYBoRvMsvi7kinChIZyI3CQA=|480837\n'
ID|1|ZXD0629|ZXD0629||HODJON||11383129|M|||221 B POLLARD RD��KAsODK�TBN�37764|||||||629Z800060|480837
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ID|1|ZXD0629|ZXD0629||QlpoOTFBWSZTWbk9uLgAAAIGCAbRiAACACAAMQZMQQaMItAUVNzxdyRThQkLk9uLgA==||11383129|M|||QlpoOTFBWSZTWT0tjHQAAAQeCEAALeAkDdQAAgAgADFNMjExMQpo0ZqBmowcuKOA3JhB1VMGcoxTGvi7kinChIHpbGOg|||||||QlpoOTFBWSZTWc5EbhIAAAQKAFNgABAgACEpppkIYBoRvMsvi7kinChIZyI3CQA=|480837\n
```

I don't need the original text without encryption i only need the encrypted one in my text. I have huge records so i cannot post entire sample here that's why i have posted a small sample. I don't know this issue is because of **replace()** or some mistake i did while implementing. Please help

Comment: `str.replace()` Replaces the text and returns it, you need to assign it back: `line = line.replace(name,ciphername).replace(address,cipheraddr)`

Comment: @LismUK Thanks a lot for the help it worked. I don't know how i never thought of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wheb calling `str.replace()` you don't change the original string value, the `replace()` function returns new value, so here you need to rewrite your original string with the replaced one:

```
line = line.replace(name,ciphername).replace(address,cipheraddr)
print line
```